# Backbone update triggers complete, but not error or success

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone with Rails, and I'm making a save call on a Backbone model. It passes the right params to the server and the server responds with a 200, and the model actually gets updated in the database.

The problem is, it gets back to the ajax call with an error. The funny thing is, when I go into the ajax call within Backbone.sync and I put error, success, and complete callbacks, it only triggers complete. The complete callback registers an error, but that's all it says.

After this the page redirects to the same url, but with all of the parameters sent in a query string:

/blah/23/index

then the Backbone save with {thing: 27, man: 82}, and everything works, but the redirects to

/blah/23/index?thing=27&man=82

I don't think it is a Backbone specific problem, because I am returning the updated object in valid JSON, and I am setting all the success, error, complete callbacks on the actual ajax call within Backbone.sync.

Anyone run into anything similar or have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

AAAHHHHH!

I spent so much time trying to figure out this problem, and it turned out to be so stupid. The Backbone.sync call came from trying to save info from a form. So I collected the data from the form and called model.save with the attributes. The Backbone.sync call was fine, but one thing was missing...

event.preventDefault()

The form was a real form with a submit button, and somewhere during some merge conflicts, the event.preventDefault() got lost.

If this happens to you, remember to call event.preventDefault() if submitting a real form, but you want it to use Backbone.sync or any ajax call, instead.